# Where should I get travel insurance for a Chinese student in Australia travelling to the USA and then travelling to China?

Tags: international-travel, insurance, chinese-citizens

I am in the USA and my girlfriend (Chinese) is currently finishing her degree in Australia. To be clear, she is a Chinese citizen on an Australian student visa at the moment.

She plans to fly from Australia to the USA, visit me for about 2 months and then fly to China from the USA.

My question is, where can/should she purchase her travel insurance from? An Australian company or a Chinese company? I know I can't ask for specific insurance company recommendations on SE but I would like some pointers on which country she should get travel insurance from?

I am afraid that an Australian company may not cover her since she will not be returning to Australia and she is not an Australian citizen.

Answer (score 1):

Since she is chinese, the best option I would think is Ping An insurance in China. They have all sorts of insurance policies I am sure you will find one that suits the needs.

NOTE: I am not in any way affiliated with Ping An but I have successfully used their services for 20 years plus so it is based on my personal experience and those of my staff in my company

Answer (score 0):

The answer here is to inquire with an Australian insurance company, they will tell you straight up whether they cover such a trip, however it will be much easier to get recompense from a Chinese insurer, her being a Chinese national, than from an Australian insurer particularly since she is not returning to Australia. Typically the insurer will pay into an AU account, and this could cause problems if she didn't have an AU bank account, or had one that she couldn't access when back home in China. Also not being back here in AU to hassle them if they were reluctant to pay up could also be a hindrance.