# What is the meaning of 'national' as in e.g. 'Australian national'?

Tags: australia, residency, citizen

From [this academia se question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/115930/career-prospects-for-a-math-phd-student-in-pure-math):

> I am an Australian national and want to live in Australia long term.

What exactly is the meaning of Australian national? like student visa? or actual citizen? or resident?

This is from a user who has also asked questions here in travel se: [Where should I get travel insurance for a Chinese student in Australia travelling to the USA and then travelling to China?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/138446/where-should-i-get-travel-insurance-for-a-chinese-student-in-australia-travellin)

Comment: If you are curious about the US, here are the rules: https://www.immihelp.com/what-is-us-national/

Comment: In the US, there's also the concept of a "US Person".  I was a "US Person" before I became a "US Citizen" (but, I was neither for the first 5 years I lived in the US (as a "Temporary non-resident alien")). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_person

Comment: @Flydog57 many people fail to understand that these terms are usually defined by specific laws, so the definitions apply only with respect to those specific laws.  For example, it is possible to be an "alien" and a "US person" while not being a "foreign national," as those terms are defined under immigration, taxation, and campaign finance law, respectively.

Comment: @phoog: Yup.  Back when I was a "Temporary non-resident alien" (for immigration purposes), I was a full-on resident for tax purposes.  These were the days before the Department of Homeland Security.  The Customs service reported to the Treasury and saw me as a resident (they wore blue shirts).  Immigration (who wore white shirts) saw me as a non-resident.  We're from Canada and we were living in New England.  Whenever we crossed the border, we had to tailor our answers to whomever was asking the questions.

Comment: @Flydog57 Ok, but that's not as weird as when you had a green card, at which time you were an "alien" under the INA and simultaneously not a "foreign national" for the purpose of federal campaign finance.

Comment: @Flydog57 also, there's no such thing as a "temporary non-resident alien" in US immigration law as far as I have seen. Do you mean "nonimmigrant alien"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129710/discussion-between-flydog57-and-phoog).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In international law, nationality and citizenship are synonymous. In domestic law, some countries distinguish between citizens and nationals, where all citizens are nationals and most nationals are citizens. I don't think Australia distinguishes between the two. So Australian citizenship is the same as Australian nationality.

Comment: thanks Brian! is it really citizen implies national but not conversely? i'd think national implies citizen but not conversely if you define national as like having a passport. what is the definition of national then in 1 of those places 'where all citizens are nationals and most nationals are citizens' ?

Comment: @BCLC Australia does not distinguish between "citizen" and "national", they are exactly the same thing: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_nationality_law

Comment: @BCLC It might include categories like permanent residents, refugees, and the like. There's also the possibility of a legal distinction between citizens and second-class nationals or slaves, like in America prior to the Civil War.

Comment: A counter example where a national may not be a citizen: [United States territories, that are not on a path of statehood.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_nationality_law#U.S._outlying_territorial_history)

Comment: @MarkJohnson thanks for commenting. is permanent resident a national? (not necessarily US. any country/state eg HK, macau, china, taiwan, france, germany, w/e)

Comment: A person who requires a **residence permit**, in general will rarely be a national. Until 1934, you were a German national (Reichsangehörige) if you were a citizen of one of the German states. After that there is only a single citizenship.

Comment: @BCLC The definition of "permanent resident" varies depending on the country. In most countries, it means someone who is not a national, who is allowed to live in that country permanently, and where such right can only be taken away if they commit a serious crime or if they spend too much time outside the country. However, some countries have multiple such immigration statuses, in which case "permanent resident" status is the one with the greatest rights: usually, permanent residents are eligible to apply for citizenship after a waiting period.

Comment: @BCLC But to be specific, it depends on the local terminology. Most Hong Kong permanent residents are Chinese nationals, while some are aliens (there is no Hong Kong nationality). US non-citizen nationals who live in the mainland are sometimes considered to be permanent residents. A permanent resident of Canada is never a national.

Comment: For Britain, a British National is a wider group than British Citizens. It includes not only British Citizens, but other groups who (very roughly) are entitled to a passport that says "British" but are not necessarily entitled to reside in the UK - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_national

Comment: @nick012000 I doubt that any country considers permanent residents or refugees to be nationals.  Can you identify one that does?  The "second-class" distinction is typically the crux of the matter, as with the present situation in the US.  Similarly, I believe Mexico considers Mexicans who haven't yet reached the age of majority to be nationals but not citizens.

Comment: @Brian "US non-citizen nationals who live in the mainland are sometimes considered to be permanent residents": by whom?  They certainly are not permanent residents under US immigration law, as that status is defined as a subcategory of "alien," and non-citizen nationals are explicitly not aliens.

Comment: @phoog For one thing, the laws that allow permanent residents to petition for their spouse and children to immigrate have been interpreted to cover non-citizen nationals as well. Also, we can look at INA 316, which requires a lawful admission for permanent residence; INA 325 permits non-citizen nationals to naturalize, but does not waive the LAPR requirement. Thus, it appears that non-citizen nationals who live in the mainland are always considered to be LAPR (though not actually aliens).

Comment: @Brian INA 325 applies to those "otherwise qualified," which means that inapplicable qualifications are ignored.  It is not possible for a US national to be "lawfully admitted for permanent residence" as defined in the INA, so "otherwise" here excludes that condition.  I cannot find any statutory or regulatory basis for treating immigrant petitions of non-citizen nationals' spouses identically to those of LPRs, only an unsupported assertion in the I-130 instructions that they "have the same rights." Are you aware of any statute, regulation, or judicial decision establishing this?

Comment: @phoog I take the opposite view: a US national in the mainland is *always* lawfully admitted for permanent residence, and in the past this was not always true. Although there's no chronological overlap between the Filipino Independence Act and the modern statutory wording, it doesn't mean the situation can't arise in the future. Let's say the US introduced immigration controls on American Samoans today but without changing any other statutory wording; the result would be that American Samoans who entered the US lawfully could naturalize, while those who entered unlawfully could not.

Comment: @phoog Sorry, when I said "a US national is always lawfully admitted for permanent residence" I meant for the purposes of INA 316. But this correction was too long to edit into the previous comment.

Comment: @phoog Regarding the I-130 petitions, see http://myattorneyusa.com/family-based-immigrant-visa-petitions-filed-by-noncitizen-nationals-usually-american-samoans .

Comment: @phoog In any case, I agree that the plain meaning of "alien lawfully admitted for permanent residence" cannot apply to a non-citizen national, because they are not an alien. But I don't think it's entirely wrong for me to say that "US non-citizen nationals who live in the mainland are sometimes considered to be permanent residents".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129709/discussion-between-phoog-and-brian).

Comment: @BCLC another issue here is that some countries don't have _any_ citizens.  Before 1948 (if I recall the year correctly), the UK did not; they used the word "subject" instead.  In the Netherlands, they don't use any word analogous to "citizen" or "subject"; they just call them "Nederlander," roughly meaning "Dutch person."  In addition to allowing for multiple classes of nationality in a single country, "national" allows one to denote "people having nationality" with reference to many countries, without having to worry about the specific word each country uses to identify its people.

Comment: in the case of subject...subject =  national? soooo what about 'We'll take Winterfell. Once the North is won, I'll declare them citizens of the realm': is it some anachronism and should be subjects/nationals instead (assuming we pretend game of thrones is set in middle ages in our world) ?

Comment: @BCLC The term "subject" is anachronistic. A monarch might refer to all other nationals of the realm as subjects, but I'm not sure if there are any monarchies in the world that still do this.

Answer (score 4):

I would parse it as this:

> I am an Australian national

He/She is a citizen of Australia.

> And want to live in Australia long term

And they are not interested in living outside of Australia

Comment: thanks Peter M! (i of course understand the latter part...)

Comment: And it could well be that they never lived in Australia or never even have been to Australia.  I know someone who was a Polish citizen by blood, but had lifed from birth in America... and decided "I am a Polish national and want to live in Poland long-term".